# CSS: auto height on containing div, 100% height on background div inside containing div

Tags: css, height

The problem, is that I have a content div which stretches its container height-wise (container and content div have auto height).

I want the background container, which is a sibling div of the content div to stretch to fill the container.  The background container contains divs to break the background into chunks.

The background and container divs have 100% width, the content container doesn't.

HTML:

```
<div id="container">  
    <div id="content">  
        Some long content here ..  
    </div>  
     <div id="backgroundContainer">  
         <div id="someDivToShowABackground"/>  
         <div id="someDivToShowAnotherBackground"/>  
    </div>  
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {
    height:auto;
    width:100%;
}

#content {
    height: auto;
    width:500px;
    margin-left:auto;
    margin-right:auto;
}

#backgroundContainer {
    height:100%;??? I want this to be the same height as container, but 100% makes it the height of the viewport.
}
```

Comment: When you set a percentage width it is a percentage of the parent element, not the whole screen. The only exception to this is the `<html>` element at the very top.

Comment: @lukewm if you could mark a correct answer it would help other users identify the right answer for your issue.

Answer (score 41):

In 2018 a lot of browsers support the [**Flexbox**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css3_flexbox.asp) and [**Grid**](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_grid.asp) which are very powerful CSS display modes that overshine classical methods such as Faux Columns or Tabular Displays (which are treated later in this answer).

In order to implement this with the Grid, it is enough to specify ***display: grid*** and ***grid-template-columns*** on the container. The ***grid-template-columns*** depends on the number of columns you have, in this example I will use 3 columns, hence the property will look: ***grid-template-columns: auto auto auto***, which basically means that each of the columns will have auto width.

Full working example with Grid:

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.grid-container {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: auto auto auto;
    width: 100%;
}

.grid-item {
    padding: 20px;
}

.a {
    background-color: DarkTurquoise;
}

.b {
    background-color: LightSalmon;
}

.c {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Three Columns with Grid</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="grid-container">
        <div class="grid-item a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien auctor, faucibus felis et, commodo magna. Sed eu molestie nibh, ac tincidunt turpis. Pellentesque accumsan nunc non arcu tincidunt auctor eget ut magna. In vel est egestas, ultricies dui a, gravida diam. Vivamus tempor facilisis lectus nec porta.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item b">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien auctor, faucibus felis et, commodo magna. Sed eu molestie nibh, ac tincidunt turpis. Pellentesque accumsan nunc non arcu tincidunt auctor eget ut magna. In vel est egestas, ultricies dui a, gravida diam. Vivamus tempor facilisis lectus nec porta. Donec commodo elit mattis, bibendum turpis eu, malesuada nunc. Vestibulum sit amet dui tincidunt, mattis nisl et, tincidunt eros. Vivamus eu ultrices sapien. Integer leo arcu, lobortis sed tellus in, euismod ultricies massa. Mauris gravida quis ligula nec dignissim. Proin elementum mattis fringilla. Donec id malesuada orci, eu aliquam ipsum. Vestibulum fermentum elementum egestas. Quisque sit amet tempor mi.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="grid-item c">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien auctor, faucibus felis et, commodo magna. Sed eu molestie nibh, ac tincidunt turpis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Another way would be to use the Flexbox by specifying ***display: flex*** on the container of the columns, and giving the columns a relevant width. In the example that I will be using, which is with 3 columns, you basically need to split 100% in 3, so it's 33.3333% (close enough, who cares about 0.00003333... which isn't visible anyway).

Full working example using Flexbox:

```css
html, body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

.flex-container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
}

.flex-column {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 33.3333%;
}

.a {
    background-color: DarkTurquoise;
}

.b {
    background-color: LightSalmon;
}

.c {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Three Columns with Flexbox</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>

    <div class="flex-container">
        <div class="flex-column a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien auctor, faucibus felis et, commodo magna. Sed eu molestie nibh, ac tincidunt turpis. Pellentesque accumsan nunc non arcu tincidunt auctor eget ut magna. In vel est egestas, ultricies dui a, gravida diam. Vivamus tempor facilisis lectus nec porta.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-column b">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien auctor, faucibus felis et, commodo magna. Sed eu molestie nibh, ac tincidunt turpis. Pellentesque accumsan nunc non arcu tincidunt auctor eget ut magna. In vel est egestas, ultricies dui a, gravida diam. Vivamus tempor facilisis lectus nec porta. Donec commodo elit mattis, bibendum turpis eu, malesuada nunc. Vestibulum sit amet dui tincidunt, mattis nisl et, tincidunt eros. Vivamus eu ultrices sapien. Integer leo arcu, lobortis sed tellus in, euismod ultricies massa. Mauris gravida quis ligula nec dignissim. Proin elementum mattis fringilla. Donec id malesuada orci, eu aliquam ipsum. Vestibulum fermentum elementum egestas. Quisque sit amet tempor mi.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="flex-column c">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Maecenas id sapien auctor, faucibus felis et, commodo magna. Sed eu molestie nibh, ac tincidunt turpis.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The Flexbox and Grid are supported by all major browsers since 2017/2018, fact also confirmed by caniuse.com: [***Can I use grid***](https://caniuse.com/#search=grid), [***Can I use flex***](https://caniuse.com/#search=flex).

There are also a number of classical solutions, used before the age of Flexbox and Grid, like ***OneTrueLayout Technique***, ***Faux Columns Technique***, ***CSS Tabular Display Technique*** and there is also a ***Layering Technique***.

I do not recommend using these methods for they have a hackish nature and are not so elegant in my opinion, but it is good to know them for academic reasons.

A solution for equally height-ed columns is the [**CSS Tabular Display Technique**](http://www.onenaught.com/posts/201/use-css-displaytable-for-layout) that means to use the ***display:table*** feature.
It works for **Firefox 2+**, **Safari 3+**, **Opera 9+** and **IE8**.

The code for the **CSS Tabular Display**:

```css
#container {
  display: table;
  background-color: #CCC;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.row {
  display: table-row;
}

.col {
  display: table-cell;
}

#col1 {
  background-color: #0CC;
  width: 200px;
}

#col2 {
  background-color: #9F9;
  width: 300px;
}

#col3 {
  background-color: #699;
  width: 200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
  <div id="rowWraper" class="row">
    <div id="col1" class="col">
      Column 1<br />Lorem ipsum<br />ipsum lorem
    </div>
    <div id="col2" class="col">
      Column 2<br />Eco cologna duo est!
    </div>
    <div id="col3" class="col">
      Column 3
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Even if there is a problem with the auto-expanding of the width of the table-cell it can be resolved easy by inserting another div withing the table-cell and giving it a fixed width. Anyway, the over-expanding of the width happens in the case of using extremely long words (which I doubt anyone would use a, let's say, **600px** long word) or some div's who's width is greater than the table-cell's width.

The [**Faux Column Technique**](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/fauxcolumns/) is the most popular classical solution to this problem, but it has some drawbacks such as, you have to resize the background tiled image if you want to resize the columns and it is also not an elegant solution.

The [**OneTrueLayout Technique**](http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight) consists of creating a padding-bottom  of an extreme big height and cut it out by bringing the real border position to the "normal logical position" by applying a negative ***margin-bottom*** of the same huge value and hiding the extent created by the padding with ***overflow: hidden*** applied to the content wraper. A simplified example would be:

Working example:

```css
.wraper {
    overflow: hidden; /* This is important */
}

.floatLeft {
    float: left;
}

.block {
    padding-left: 20px;
    padding-right: 20px;
    padding-bottom: 30000px; /* This is important */
    margin-bottom: -30000px; /* This is important */
    width: 33.3333%;
    box-sizing: border-box; /* This is so that the padding right and left does not affect the width */
}

.a {
    background-color: DarkTurquoise;
}

.b {
    background-color: LightSalmon;
}

.c {
    background-color: LightSteelBlue;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
  <title>OneTrueLayout</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="wraper">
        <div class="block floatLeft a">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada ipsum pretium tellus condimentum aliquam. Donec eget tempor mi, a consequat enim. Mauris a massa id nisl sagittis iaculis.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block floatLeft b">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada ipsum pretium tellus condimentum aliquam. Donec eget tempor mi, a consequat enim. Mauris a massa id nisl sagittis iaculis. Duis mattis diam vitae tellus ornare, nec vehicula elit luctus. In auctor urna ac ante bibendum, a gravida nunc hendrerit. Praesent sed pellentesque lorem. Nam neque ante, egestas ut felis vel, faucibus tincidunt risus. Maecenas egestas diam massa, id rutrum metus lobortis non. Sed quis tellus sed nulla efficitur pharetra. Fusce semper sapien neque. Donec egestas dolor magna, ut efficitur purus porttitor at. Mauris cursus, leo ac porta consectetur, eros quam aliquet erat, condimentum luctus sapien tellus vel ante. Vivamus vestibulum id lacus vel tristique.</p>
        </div>
        <div class="block floatLeft c">
            <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras malesuada ipsum pretium tellus condimentum aliquam. Donec eget tempor mi, a consequat enim. Mauris a massa id nisl sagittis iaculis. Duis mattis diam vitae tellus ornare, nec vehicula elit luctus. In auctor urna ac ante bibendum, a gravida nunc hendrerit.</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

The **Layering Technique** must be a very neat solution that involves absolute positioning of div's withing a main relative positioned wrapper div. It basically consists of a number of child divs and the main div. The main div has imperatively ***position: relative*** to it's css attribute collection. The children of this div are all imperatively ***position:absolute***. The children must have ***top*** and ***bottom*** set to ***0*** and ***left-right*** dimensions set to accommodate the columns with each another. For example if we have two columns, one of width **100px** and the other one of **200px**, considering that we want the 100px in the left side and the **200px** in the right side, the left column must have ***{left: 0; right: 200px}*** and the right column ***{left: 100px; right: 0;}***

In my opinion the unimplemented 100% height within an automated height container is a major drawback and the W3C should consider revising this attribute (which since 2018 is solvable with Flexbox and Grid).

Other resources: **[link1](http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/equal-height-columns/), [link2](http://www.ejeliot.com/blog/61), [link3](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/multicolumnlayouts/), [link4](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/), [link5 (important)](http://css-tricks.com/fluid-width-equal-height-columns/)**

Comment: The OneTrueLayout doesn't seem to work anymore, at least with Chrome 43 on Mac: http://jsbin.com/mepucolagi/1/edit?html,output

Answer (score 9):

Make `#container` to `display:inline-block`

```
#container {
  height: auto;
  width: 100%;
  display: inline-block;
}

#content {
  height: auto;
  width: 500px;
  margin-left: auto;
  margin-right: auto;
}

#backgroundContainer {
  height: 200px; /*200px is example, change to what you want*/
  width: 100%;
}
```

Also see: [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp)

Answer (score 5):

Okay so someone is probably going to slap me for this answer, but I use jQuery to solve all my irritating problems and it turns out that I just used something today to fix a similar issue. Assuming you use jquery:

```
$("#content").sibling("#backgroundContainer").css("height",$("#content").outerHeight());
```

this is untested but I think you can see the concept here. Basically after it is loaded, you can get the height (outerHeight includes padding + borders, innerHeight for the content only). Hope that helps.

Here is how you bind it to the window resize event:

```
$(window).resize(function() {
  $("#content").sibling("#backgroundContainer").css("height",$("#content").outerHeight());
});
```

Comment: AAAAAH!? they can turn it OFF? hehe.

Comment: This won't do unfortunately, even if I was happy with using javascript, if the dynamics of the page change while the user is on it, the jquery script would have to be called again, and that is just asking for unwanted complexity.

Comment: That is practical but unfortunately it is against the principle of separation of concerns, where the CSS is responsible for how the site should look and the JavaScript is responsible for how it should behave.

Comment: @AndrewG.H. Yeah there are a lot of legitimate reasons to not use javascript to solve this sort of thing now days. I will tell you though that declaring a principle like "separation of concerns" as some law that should never be abandoned for the needs of a solution or customer isn't very good either. Practicality and pragmatism must color the work of the engineer, else in imagination we would be lost and incomplete forever.

Comment: @Gabriel I never said that this principle should be respected or to face the consequences of the inferno, I'm merely suggesting that it's always good to aim for the good practices, and I do agree with what you said about pragmatism and making the clients happy because I'm a freelancer myself so I know the pain.

Answer (score 3):

Somewhere you will need to set a fixed height, instead of using auto everywhere. You will find that if you set a fixed height on your content and/or container, then using auto for things inside it will work.

Also, your boxes will still expand height-wise with more content in, even though you have set a height for it - so don't worry about that :)

```
#container {
  height:500px;
  min-height:500px;
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately, the container div won't expand according to the content div's height. If the content div contains content that makes it expand to 600px in height, it will simply overflow the container div unless the container div is set to height:auto.

Comment: Thanks for your effort, any other ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't have to set `height: 100%` at any point if you want your container to fill the page. Chances are, your problem is rooted in the fact that you haven't cleared the floats in the container's children. There are quite a few ways to solve this problem, mainly adding `overflow: hidden` to the container.

```
#container { overflow: hidden; }
```

Should be enough to solve whatever height problem you're having.

Answer (score 1):

Just a quick note because I had a hard time with this.

By using #container { overflow: hidden; } the page I had started to have layout issues in Firefox and IE (when the zoom would go in and out the content would bounce in and out of the parent div).

The solution to this issue is to add a display: inline-block; to the same div with overflow:hidden;

Answer (score 0):

I ended up making 2 display:table;

```
#container-tv { /* Tiled background */
    display:table;
    width:100%;
    background-image: url(images/back.jpg);
    background-repeat: repeat;  
}
#container-body-background { /* center column but not 100% width */ 
    display:table;
    margin:0 auto;
    background-image:url(images/middle-back.png);
    background-repeat: repeat-y;

}
```

This made it have a tiled background image with a background image in the middle as a column. It stretches to 100% height of page not just 100% of browser window size

Answer (score 0):

Try excluding height from the style element.

i.e. neither give height:100% nor to any other value.

Answer (score 0):

```
{
    height:100vh;
    width:100vw;
}
```