# Set minimum height of container div from maximum height of its grandchild's divs

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have this code working

```
$('document').ready(function(){

var max = Math.max.apply(null, $(".content").map(function() {
    return $(this).outerHeight();
}));
$(".container").height(max);

});
```

For this HTML

```
<div class="container">
<section class="section" >
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner_content">
             <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="section" >
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner_content">
             <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
<section class="section" >
    <div class="content">
        <div class="inner_content">
             <p>...</p>
        </div>
    </div>
</section>
</div>
```

It outputs

```
<div class="container" style="height: 500px;">...</div>
```

I just want "min-height: 500px;" in place of "height: 500px;"

Can anyone help? Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://api.jquery.com/css/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this:

```
$(".container").height(max);
```

to this:

```
$(".container").css("min-height",max);
```

Answer (score 1):

(**Recommended**) You might consider: [Plain HTML/CSS columns techniques](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2779554/css-auto-height-on-containing-div-100-height-on-background-div-inside-contain/11284933#11284933)

Another option would be to do this manually and in JavaScript you might want to get all the heights of the grandchildren and get compare the maximum then set the attribute using [How to set minHeight in javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_minheight.asp) with that value

Answer (score 1):

Use JQuery .css() method to set max-height property.

```
$(".container").css('max-height',max);
```