# Sidebar Doesn't Force to touch bottom of the parent Div

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap sidebar. It works and designs nicely, however whatever I tried, I couldn't figure out how to force the height of the sidebar to lengthen until it touches the bottom of the parent. [You can see it on Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25304/), (please stretch the view to make it equal to medium screen)

I tried stuff like

```
.sidebar { 
     height: 100%;
     bottom: 0;
     height: 600px // works but I don't want to give it static
}
```

Is the only way trying to get the height of parent div using Javascript and manipulate sidebar?

---

Full chunk:

```
<div class="container-fluid" style="background-color:green">
  <div class="row row-offcanvas row-offcanvas-left active">
    <div class="col-md-2 sidebar-offcanvas">
      <ul class="nav nav-sidebar">
        <li><a href="#">A</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">B</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">C</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<style>
   .nav-sidebar {
       background-color:lightgray;
       height: 100%;
   }

   .container-fluid {
       height: 500px;
   }
</style>
```

Updated Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25305/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the parent has a height set, then the child can use `height:100%` to expand it to that same height. And then you can make the grandchild `height:100%` to do the same.

```
.sidebar, .sidebar-offcanvas, .row-offcanvas {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/25308/)

Comment: Thanks, but what if it is dynamically determined and not hardcoded in as 600px? I couldn't make it do the same in the project :/ `.sidebar, .sidebar-offcanvas, .row-offcanvas {
  height:100%
  }` this approach doesn't work :/

Comment: Okay. There are a few different ways of doing this; it just depends on what exactly you need from it. Have a look [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11284933/1086525).

Comment: I tried adding `height: 100%` and `bottom: 0` to grandchildren, until container-fluid, however, it doesn't work in dynamically set height :/

Comment: Did you check out that link I gave you? There are a few different ways of achieving this, but only you will know which will be best for you. You might want to try them all out to see how they work. After that you could come back and amend your original post to be more specific, showing what you've tried and what you need (more specifically).